# DrRacket: How to smoothly draw large bitmap on canvas

Tags: user-interface, racket

```
(require racket/draw
     mred) 

(define bitmap-canvas%
  (class canvas%
  (init-field [bitmap #f])
  (inherit get-dc)
  (define/override (on-paint)
     (send (get-dc) draw-bitmap bitmap 0 0))
  (define/public (set-bitmap! new-bitmap)
     (displayln "setting bitmap")
     (set! bitmap new-bitmap))
  (super-new)))

(define bitmap (read-bitmap
               "some-stringPath-to-bitmap-source"))

(define f (new frame% [label "foo"] [width 100] [height 100]))

(define the-canvas (new bitmap-canvas% [parent f] [bitmap bitmap] [min-width 500] [min-height 500]))
(send f show #t)
```

I have to above code to show a bitmap within a Canvas, contained in a Frame. However, when the bitmap has large dimensions, (1200x900) for example, you cannot see all of it. How can I adapt the code so that the entire bitmap is scaled to fit in the canvas?

Thanks